# How should I label a large number of lines in a matplotlib plot?

Tags: matplotlib, colors, label, legend, lines

I have a plot that features a large number of lines. I can add a legend to it, but the large number of lines means that it can be hard to spot the line to which a legend colour corresponds. What would be a good way to add a clear label to lines?

[image]

Comment: The "how to deal with plots with many lines" is a serious issue and in 2015 is still poorly discussed on the Internet. The only trick I know: order the labels by the value of the curves at the beginning(min value of x-axis) (or at their peak). In this way the reader can understand which label corresponds to which line by just counting the curves from the one with highest values to the one with lowest values.  And of course he/she can still relays on the colour (if not colour blind). This trick also helps because sometime people are only interested in the lines with highest and lowest values.

Comment: Are you sure this is the best way to plot the data?  What's actually being shown?  It looks like you only have 4N data points where N is the number of lines.  Is this categorical data?

Comment: @wflynny Each line represents a particular model. The x-axis represents an important parameter of the models and the y-axis represents a score achieved by each model.

Comment: @d3pd Are you more interested in comparing models given values of the parameter or viewing model scores as a function of the parameter?  I ask because you could plot something like [this for the former](https://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/pairgrid_dotplot.html).  Or even more compact, 4 [histograms/boxplots/etc](https://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/elaborate_violinplot.html), one at each of the parameter values.  Are there [classes of models](https://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/scatterplot_categorical.html) to group things?

Comment: You can also try with a contour plot or a surface plot.

Comment: @wflynny Thank you for your helpful suggestions. I'm a little weary of the multiple-plots approach because of the large number of models I'm looking at, but the violinplot approach might just work.

Comment: @nicoguaro Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, perhaps I could try making a surface out of all of the plots.